Cannot privately connect to Azure SQL Server instance
I have created an instance of Microsoft SQL Server on Azure, following all steps and guides. I disabled public access and created private endpoint and corresponding DNS. All in the same region, subscription and subnet. There is no way to connect privately (I have VPN to this subnet) neither by IP nor by hostname. Connecting by hostname goes public and returns the message that public access is disabled. What have I missed?
BTW: when I enable public access and add a firewall rule, I can connect without any problem.
I tried to create another SQL Server, paying even more attention to instructions and involving a coworker in the process. The same result: unable to connect privately.

This is not a full answer (we don't really have enough to go on) but here are some potential issues and troubleshooting steps. Furthermore, this is based on my experience only with a similar setup.
I'm assuming by 'SQL Server instance' you're talking about Azure SQL Managed Instances. If not, then not all of these apply.
Firstly, in your description, it's not clear that a Private Endpoint is needed. When creating an Virtual Network with private networking (e.g., disabling public access on resources and adding Private Endpoints to various resources), you should note that SQL Managed Instances work a bit differently. When created, they also create a dedicated subnet and NSG and they get their IP from there.
Private endpoints for SQL MIs instead appear to be for allowing access across VNETs - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/connectivity-architecture-overview?view=azuresql#communication-overview
My initial guess (based on my own experiences) is that it is a DNS issue.
A SQL MI with public access disabled, but no private endpoint, will have a public DNS entry - except that that entry will point to the internal VNET (e.g., 10.0.10.210).
Ideally, if you have a VPN into the same Azure VNET, then fundamentally
a) When trying to connect, it checks DNS to get the correct IP (e.g., in your private IP range)
b) Your router/etc is set up so that it uses the VPN when accessing those IP ranges (i.e., your connection takes the correct path)
c) There are no firewall rules etc (e.g., on NSGs) blocking your path.
So, with that said, here are some troubleshooting steps.

Check your DNS to ensure you're getting the correct IP address. The easiest method (from a Windows box) is to run (from the command line) nslookup <servername>.<stuff>.database.windows.net. It will return an IP address (hopefully). Check that it is correct.
If it is not correct, you need to check how your DNS is set up. If you're using Private Endpoints, the IP addresses of them are not public. Instead, you need to ensure your DNS settings can forward requests to Azure. This will involve

Determining your main DNS source (e.g., whether you use a server as DNS, or your router, or similar).
Create an Azure 'Private DNS resolver' - but be mindful of the cost
Ensure your main DNS source uses 'conditional forwarding' to pass DNS requests for database.windows.net through to the private DNS resolver


Ensure that if you try to access the IP address, your router/etc forwards it appropriately.
Also note that the MI creates its own subnet and NSG - check the NSG isn't blocking your traffic. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/connectivity-architecture-overview?view=azuresql#network-requirements - particularly the part about NSGs. Ensure your NSG allows your VPN endpoint to access the SQL MI on port 1433.

